# Delete nonsense columns in r

Tags: r

I have this data

```
vector <- c("Pos_emaO_dO_UP", "Pos_emaO_dO_D", "Pos_emaC_dC_UP", "Pos_emaC_dC_D",
            "Pos_emaC_dO_D", "Pos_emaC_dO_UP", "Pos_emaO_dC_UP", "Pos_emaO_dC_D")
```

and this function

```
comb <- as.data.frame(combn(vector, 4))
comb
```

which gives me this table

```
V1             V2             V3             V4             V5             V6             V7             V8             V9            V10            V11            V12
1 Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP
2  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D
3 Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D
4  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D
             V13            V14            V15            V16            V17            V18            V19            V20            V21            V22            V23            V24
1 Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP
2  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP
3 Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaC_dO_UP
4 Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D  Pos_emaO_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D
             V25            V26            V27            V28            V29            V30            V31            V32            V33            V34            V35            V36
1 Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP  Pos_emaO_dO_D
2 Pos_emaC_dC_UP  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP
3 Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaC_dC_D
4  Pos_emaO_dC_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D  Pos_emaO_dC_D Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D  Pos_emaO_dC_D  Pos_emaO_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D
             V37            V38            V39            V40            V41            V42            V43            V44            V45            V46            V47           V48
1  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D Pos_emaO_dO_D
2 Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D Pos_emaC_dC_D
3  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D Pos_emaC_dO_D
4 Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D  Pos_emaO_dC_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP Pos_emaO_dC_D
             V49            V50            V51            V52            V53            V54            V55            V56            V57            V58            V59            V60
1  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP
2  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D
3 Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaC_dO_UP
4 Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D  Pos_emaO_dC_D Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D  Pos_emaO_dC_D  Pos_emaO_dC_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D
             V61            V62            V63            V64            V65            V66            V67            V68            V69            V70
1 Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D
2  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaC_dO_UP
3 Pos_emaO_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP
4  Pos_emaO_dC_D Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D  Pos_emaO_dC_D  Pos_emaO_dC_D Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D  Pos_emaO_dC_D  Pos_emaO_dC_D  Pos_emaO_dC_D
>
```

and I need to delete these columns which has the same names (before `_UP` or `_D`) both in one column. It means, for example, delete `V1:V20` (always the same name twice) and first column which I need is `V21`.

I have huge dataset, this is only example, any advice how to do it? thanks

Comment: Is this now a completely new question? If so, you should roll back your edit and create a new question. We put effort in to help you and future generations of R enthusiasts :)

Comment: It is, I'll do. I am new into R, but so interested in. I appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: I've reverted the question to its original state. That way your exact issue is clearer to other people with similar problems. (For future reference, you can undo edits by clicking the "edited x ago" link just below the question, and then clicking the "rollback" link next to the version you want to reinstate.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1):

To omit columns with duplicated string stems you can do the following, which subsets data frame with a logical vector that results from checking each column for duplication of the string stem:

```
comb[!sapply(comb, function(x) any(duplicated(sub('_D|_UP', '', x))))]

#              V21            V22            V23            V24
# 1 Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP
# 2 Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP
# 3  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaC_dO_UP
# 4 Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D
#              V27            V28            V29            V30
# 1 Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP
# 2  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D
# 3  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaC_dO_UP
# 4 Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D
#              V41            V42            V43            V44
# 1  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D
# 2 Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dC_UP
# 3  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaC_dO_UP
# 4 Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D
#              V47           V48            V49            V50
# 1  Pos_emaO_dO_D Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D
# 2  Pos_emaC_dC_D Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dC_D
# 3  Pos_emaC_dO_D Pos_emaC_dO_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaC_dO_UP
# 4 Pos_emaO_dC_UP Pos_emaO_dC_D Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants to remove entire columns that contain "duplicated" elements.

Comment: Exactly, this is not what am I looking for. I don't want to delete only the duplicated part of column. The result should be new data.frame without these columns where was duplicated variables.

Comment: In that case you just want this: `comb[!sapply(comb, function(x) any(duplicated(sub('_D|_UP', '', x))))]`. Feel free to update to this, if you like, @agstudy.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you had in mind? My understanding is that for each of `Pos_emaC_dC`, `Pos_emaC_dO`, `Pos_emaO_dC` and `Pos_emaO_dO`, you want either `*_UP` or `*_D`, but not both. Below, I split your vector according to which of these four pairs the elements belong to. We can then use `expand.grid` to create our combinations, choosing only a single element from each group.

```
expand.grid(split(vector, sub('_D|_UP', '', vector)))

#       Pos_emaC_dC    Pos_emaC_dO    Pos_emaO_dC    Pos_emaO_dO
# 1  Pos_emaC_dC_UP  Pos_emaC_dO_D Pos_emaO_dC_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP
# 2   Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D Pos_emaO_dC_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP
# 3  Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP
# 4   Pos_emaC_dC_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP Pos_emaO_dO_UP
# 5  Pos_emaC_dC_UP  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dC_D Pos_emaO_dO_UP
# 6   Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dC_D Pos_emaO_dO_UP
# 7  Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dO_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D Pos_emaO_dO_UP
# 8   Pos_emaC_dC_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D Pos_emaO_dO_UP
# 9  Pos_emaC_dC_UP  Pos_emaC_dO_D Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dO_D
# 10  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dO_D
# 11 Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dO_D
# 12  Pos_emaC_dC_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP Pos_emaO_dC_UP  Pos_emaO_dO_D
# 13 Pos_emaC_dC_UP  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dC_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D
# 14  Pos_emaC_dC_D  Pos_emaC_dO_D  Pos_emaO_dC_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D
# 15 Pos_emaC_dC_UP Pos_emaC_dO_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D
# 16  Pos_emaC_dC_D Pos_emaC_dO_UP  Pos_emaO_dC_D  Pos_emaO_dO_D
```

Comment: I worked with expand.grid but the problem is that I need to use combn to be able make o combinations of various number of variables (which combn allows me).

Comment: You didn't make that clear in your question, which only shows combination with four elements. Are there ever instances where you want to allow the `_D` but not the `_UP` (or vice versa) for a given variable?

Comment: I worked with expand.grid but the problem is that I need to use combn to be able make o combinations of various number of variables (which combn allows me). Understand, I need to find the combination of variables (included the best number of used variables) which fits the best to my depended variable.

Comment: No it isnt. Sorry it was my mistake, I wrote the combn function cause I need it's output and forget that anybody could solve it trough the expand.grid

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: I HAVE FOUND THE SOLUTION:
I wrote this function and let it run trough and it works.

```
subf<-function (x){
  rc<-allcombin[[x]][!sapply(allcombin[[x]], function(x) any(duplicated(sub('_D|_UP', '', x))))]
  return(rc)
}
lists<-c(1:length(allcombin))
rc_all<-lapply(lists,subf)
```

I've been working with the code which @agstudy and @jbaums showed me
The source vector is here

```
vrvector<-c("Pos_emaO_dO_UP","Pos_emaO_dO_D","Pos_emaC_dC_UP","Pos_emaC_dC_D","Pos_emaC_dO_D","Pos_emaC_dO_UP","Pos_emaO_dC_UP","Pos_emaO_dC_D")

library(combinat)

rc<-comb[!sapply(comb, function(x) any(duplicated(sub('_D|_UP', '', x))))]
```

but that was written to work with one df like this example below

```
comb<-as.data.frame(combn(vrvector,4))
rc<-comb[!sapply(comb, function(x) any(duplicated(sub('_D|_UP', '', x))))]
```

But now I see this code doesn't work with lists, which I need to. So if I use the function below

```
    allcomb<-function (x){
      combinations<-as.data.frame(combn(vrvector,x))
      return(combinations)
    }
    vcomb<-c(2:(length(vrvector)/2))
    allcombin<-lapply(vcomb,allcomb)
    allcombin
```

and get df's for all possible number of variables collected to list and use the function like this

```
rc<-allcombin[!sapply(allcombin, function(x) any(duplicated(sub('_D|_UP', '', x))))]
```

The result is

```
list()
```

Any advices for changes in the code to work for all df's in list as well as for one single df? Thanks