# Subset must be logical error in R

Tags: r

I use this code and try to subset it. The source data are below

```
library(quantmod)
library(combinat)
getSymbols("AAPL",from="2012-01-01")
data<-AAPL
p1<-4  
dO<-data[,1]
dC<-data[,4]
emaO<-EMA(dO,n=p1)
emaC<-EMA(dC,n=p1)
Pos_emaO_dO_UP<-emaO>dO
Pos_emaO_dO_D<-emaO<dO
Pos_emaC_dC_UP<-emaC>dC
Pos_emaC_dC_D<-emaC<dC
Pos_emaC_dO_D<-emaC<dO
Pos_emaC_dO_UP<-emaC>dO
Pos_emaO_dC_UP<-emaO>dC
Pos_emaO_dC_D<-emaO<dC
    frame<-
data.frame(Pos_emaO_dO_UP,Pos_emaO_dO_D,Pos_emaC_dC_UP,Pos_emaC_dC_D,Pos_emaC_dO_D,Pos_emaC_dO_UP,Pos_emaO_dC_UP,Pos_emaO_dC_D)
    colnames(frame)<-vector<-c("Pos_emaO_dO_UP","Pos_emaO_dO_D","Pos_emaC_dC_UP","Pos_emaC_dC_D","Pos_emaC_dO_D","Pos_emaC_dO_UP","Pos_emaO_dC_UP","Pos_emaO_dC_D")
```

This is the code was used to take out the nonsense columns

```
comb<-as.data.frame(combn(vector,4))
comb


rc<-comb[!sapply(comb, function(x) any(duplicated(sub('_D|_UP', '', x))))]
```

And then I've tried to subset the main frame by combination of variables from first column

```
kb<-as.vector(rc[,1])
    vr<-paste(kb,collapse=" & ")
    subset(frame,vr)
```

But the result is : subset must be logical. I need to subset the frame by all these combinations like

```
subset(frame,Pos_emaO_dO_D & Pos_emaC_dC_UP & Pos_emaC_dO_D & Pos_emaO_dC_UP) #etc.
```

one by one a then use on each subset function which I wrote to analyse

```
subsetit<-function(x,y){
  f<-head(subset(main_table,y & x),-1)
  1d_l_prof<-nrow(f[f$Profit_L_1>0.1,])/nrow(f)
  2d_l_prof<-(nrow(f[f$Profit_L_2>0.1,])/nrow(f))/2
  3d_l_prof<-(nrow(f[f$Profit_L_3>0.1,])/nrow(f))/3
  4d_l_prof<-(nrow(f[f$Profit_L_4>0.1,])/nrow(f))/4
  5d_l_prof<-(nrow(f[f$Profit_L_5>0.1,])/nrow(f))/5
  6d_l_prof<-(nrow(f[f$Profit_L_6>0.1,])/nrow(f))/6
  7d_l_prof<-(nrow(f[f$Profit_L_7>0.1,])/nrow(f))/7
  8d_l_prof<-(nrow(f[f$Profit_L_8>0.1,])/nrow(f))/8
  9d_l_prof<-(nrow(f[f$Profit_L_9>0.1,])/nrow(f))/9
  10d_l_prof<-(nrow(f[f$Profit_L_10>0.1,])/nrow(f))/10
  df<-data.frame(1d_l_prof,2d_l_prof,3d_l_prof,4d_l_prof,5d_l_prof,6d_l_prof,7d_l_prof,8d_l_prof,9d_l_prof,10d_l_prof)
  return(df)
}
```

Where should be the problem of subset error? 
Will works some

```
lapply(rc[,c(1:length(rc))],subsetit] ?
```

Comment: @jbaums There is the new question :)

Comment: How is this question different from your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24032398/delete-nonsense-columns)? They seem the same to me ....

Comment: The other question was different, I've changed it then, but jbaums told me that is better to create a new one, so I did it. Firstly was different. I'll delete it to make it clear. Thanks

Comment: It is not allowed me to delete if it has answers, sorry my mistake. It won't be repeated.

Comment: It appears your `vr` is a character string. If you go this route, you'll need to do the infamous `eval(parse(paste0('subset(frame,' , vr,')' )))` construction.

Comment: There is some mistake in this code. > eval(parse(paste0('subset(frame,' , vr,')' )))
Error in file(filename, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r") :
  cannot open file 'subset(frame,Pos_emaO_dO_UP & Pos_emaC_dC_UP & Pos_emaC_dO_D & Pos_emaO_dC_UP)': No such file or directory

Comment: Ooops, sorry:  need `...parse(text=...`

Answer (score 0):

Posting comment as an answer since Bury says it works:

It appears your vr is a character string. If you go this route, you'll need to do the infamous `eval(parse(text= paste0('subset(frame,' , vr,')' )))` construction.